# selenium chrome driver stops working after publish application

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have this code. And I put `chromedriver.exe` in my solution folder bin>>debug

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--disable-notifications");

IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();

driver.Url = url;
```

It works ok when I debug application but after publishing it throws an exception

[image]

what can I do? It's simple console application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try newer ChromeDriver and Selenium versions. I have just checked this code on Selenium.WebDriver 3.4.0 and Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver 2.30.0.1

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41) on port 2935
Only local connections are allowed.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

It works fine for debug and release versions.

Comment: you have installed chrome driver using nuget?

Comment: after publishing app it throws that error: `Unhandled Exception: OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException: The chromedriver.exe file does not exist in the current directory or in a directory on the PATH environment variable.`

Comment: Yes, sure. Here's the page: [NuGet package - Selenium WebDriver ChromeDriver](https://github.com/jsakamoto/nupkg-selenium-webdriver-chromedriver/). I then add file `chromedriver.exe` from packages folder **as link** into the Project and in file's Properties set "Copy if newer" thus it copies driver into your bin automatically on building.

Comment: Didn't know if I should add it in properties. thanks now it works fine

Comment: You welcome :)
You can set it to "Copy always". In this case it will allow you to have only one instance of driver running.

Comment: Also an important thing: you should readd the file into the Project and set again the Properties for each ChromeDriver update.